# Is an UpperCase Index required if all values are uppercase?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table `ATable` with an index created on `a` and `b`.

I know that all values in `a` and `b` are stored in uppercase.

I suspect that the index behaves correctly in this instance

```
select
    *
from
    BTable b 
join
    ATable a on upper(b.a) = a.a and upper(b.b) = a.b;
```

but what if I do a select like

```
select
    *
from
    BTable b 
join
    ATable a on upper(b.a) = upper(a.a) and upper(b.b) = upper(a.b);
```

Will my index be used? Or do I need to create an index on `ATable(upper(a), upper(b))`?

---

The collation is:

```
select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDB','Collation');
-----
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: it depends on your collation, but if you ran that query and checked the execution plan you'd see if the join predicate used the index or not.

Comment: If you have a case sensitive collation that is likely going to be nonSARGable anyway.

Comment: possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514253/sql-server-2008-unique-column-that-is-case-sensitive

Comment: Why do you need a.a with upper if a.a is uppercase?

Comment: @scsimon I've been asked to review a query on a database where I currently don't have permission to run an execution plan. I suspect this combination may be problem but I don't know of any way to verify right now. I'll add the collation to the question.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 it would have been done to protect against the possibility of non-uppercase values being added in the future. I'm interested right now in determining if there is a performance impact against the current dataset.

Comment: @SeanLange makes a good point about sargability... functions tend to do this

Comment: how about a trigger instead?...to ensure data is uppercase

Comment: I don't think a trigger is necessary here @Ctznkane525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need an upper case index.

Since you are using a case insensitive collation, the `upper` isn't needed in the query either and as [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) stated, the `upper` function could make that query [nonSARGable](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/09/13/what-is-a-sargable-predicate/) (it didn't in the example below). If you remove the `upper` and there is an index on those columns, it could be used. I say could because you are doing `select *` so the optimizer may choose a table scan since you need all columns.

To elaborate a bit more, since the collation is case insensitive `abc` is the same as `AbC`, thus the same results would be returned with or without your `upper` function but performance wouldn't be the same because:

- The `upper` function itself takes time and resources to run
- It can make the query nonSARGable meaning your indexes could *not* be used and thus, hurt performance

You can see this in action by checking [out this query, with it's execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkahptNwQ). You'll see the function hurts!

**Here's the code, and a picture of the execution plan from that link**

```
create table #t1(c1 varchar(8) not null)
alter table #t1 add constraint t1_PK primary key (c1)

create table #t2(c1 varchar(8) not null)
alter table #t2 add constraint t2_PK primary key (c1)

insert into #t1
values
('aaa'),
('BBB'),
('ccc'),
('DDD')

insert into #t2
values
('AAA'),
('bbb'),
('Ccc'),
('dDD')

select *
from #t1 t1
inner join #t2 t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1

select *
from #t1 t1
inner join #t2 t2
on upper(t1.c1) = upper(t2.c1)

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Well than ya Mr Lange!